# Elixir: what is right way for fetching external API in separate processes

Tags: elixir, task, agent

I want to fetch data from external API: it's a similar request when change only one param (page). I would to get it parallel processed but gather data in one place.
What is the right way for done it in Elixir?
I've made some investigation and have only one solution for now:
use `Agent` for save data from API calls and `Task` for a call API.

Comment: What’s wrong with `Agent` and `Task` then?

Comment: Nothing wrong but I'm not sure is it wright way because I've just begun learn Elixir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Task.async_stream](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async_stream/3) might fit your needs.

```
(1..10) 
|> Task.async_stream(fn n -> get_page(n) end, max_concurrency: 10, timeout: 30_000, ordered: true)
|> Stream.map(fn {:ok, data} -> data end)
|> Enum.to_list()
```